# Searching with relational operators in a Marklogic custom constraint

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way to use relational operators to search using a MarkLogic custom constraint?

For a normal range query, I can search either for an exact match ("thing:123") or by using relational operators ("thing LT 123"). However, when I write a custom constraint, only the exact match works. It never enters the 'parse' method if I use relational operators.

An utterly trivial example which simply returns nothing if the constraint is triggered in any way:

The xquery library module (it uses the 'Multi-Format' signature specified [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_76809), but the others do the same thing) :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace test = "http://test/search";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare function test:parse(
  $query as item(), 
  $right-or-option as element())
as schema-element(cts:query) {
  <cts:false-query/> (: don't return anything :)
};
```

XQuery that can run in qconsole:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare variable $OPTIONS := <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <debug>true</debug>
    <constraint name="test">
        <custom facet="false">
            <parse apply="parse" ns="http://test/search" at="/ext/search/test-search.xqy"/>
        </custom>
    </constraint>
</options>;

search:search("test GT foo",$OPTIONS)
```

Searching for "test:foo" creates the correct query using `cts:false-query()`. Searching for "test GT foo" returns all documents.

The response when using the relational operator contains this:

```
<search:qtext>test GT foo</search:qtext>
<search:report id="SEARCH-FLWOR">(cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:and-query((), ()), ("score-logtfidf",cts:score-order("descending")), 1))[1 to 10]</search:report>
<search:warning id="SEARCH-IGNOREDQTEXT">[test GT foo]</search:warning>
```

It seems to be recognizing it as more than a plain text search, but it doesn't send it into my parse function. How can I make it call my function?

In case it matters, the real constraint is using a triple-range-query, which does support operators (assuming I can get them in to it). If there's a better way to do triple queries via search:search that would solve my current problem, but I'd like to know how to make custom constraints recognize relational operators regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: inequality operators (LT, GT, etc) are not supported with custom constraints, but there are ways around that.

Longer version:

I had thought this worked, so I did some testing (for the record, I'm using MarkLogic 8.0-5.8). I believe your search options get mixed with the default options (otherwise the "test:foo" case wouldn't work). Those options include this:

```
<search:grammar>
  <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LT" tokenize="word">LT</search:joiner>
</search:grammar>
```

This says, when you see two tokens separated by "LT", [apply the `constraint` function](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_61596) to figure out what to do with them. That led me to look up what that `constraint` function does. After digging in a few levels, I discovered these lines of code in the Search API library:

```
else if ($compare and (empty($matched-constraint/opt:range) or $is-bucketed)) 
then <search:annotation warning="SEARCH-IGNOREDQTEXT:[{concat($matched-constraint/@name/string()," ",$compare," ",$qtext-rhs)}]"/>
```

I'm sure you recognize that annotation. In my testing, `$compare` was "LT" and `$matched-constraint` was my test constraint. This line requires that [the constraint be a range type](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_42752) for the parser to apply the LT to this.

### Workarounds

I see two choices.

1. Implement a different function that you can specify in the `joiner` part of the Search API grammar (`apply="my-constraint"`) and make it work for custom constraints.
2. Implement multiple versions of your parsing function and set up multiple constraints: constraint `test-lt` will apply `parse-lt`, etc.

*Note: you may be tempted to poke into the implementation of the Search API and hack it to work for your case (it is, after all, just an XQuery library). Don't. If you do, your change will disappear as soon as you upgrade MarkLogic, and if that upgrade includes any changes to that library, you'll be making things difficult on yourself.*

If you have a relationship to someone at MarkLogic, you can ask that person to file an RFE to allow these joiners to work with custom constraints. Let me know if you don't.

Comment: I just put in a request to MarkLogic... I'll update this if they come back with anything new. In the meantime I'll see what I can do with the joiners. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your test constraint, it is marked as facet="false". I haven't verified, but I suspect that is the reason why it is not acting on `test GT foo`, but is on `test:foo`. Implement a fake facet finish (start is optional I thought), and toggle the flag to see if your test constraint works for the GT case as well.

Regarding triple-range-query, there is this triple-range-constraint ready for use, but works best with structured-queries (like when using REST-api /v1/search and such). It might give you some inspiration though:

https://github.com/patrickmcelwee/triple-range-constraint

HTH!

Comment: Actually, I took the facet="true" out to post it here :) Thanks for the link,

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else needs this, I got a custom joiner function to handle both regular range indexes and custom ones so users could use the same operators for both.

There's some configuration in the option constraints to tell it what to look for when searching and a grammar section that changes the relational operators from the default 'constraint' to a custom function:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" xmlns:ps="http://my.namespace">
    <constraint name="quantity">
        <custom facet="false">
            <parse apply="parse" ns="http://test/search" at="/ext/search/test-search.xqy"/>
        </custom>
        <annotation>
            <ps:config compareSupported="true">
                <ps:triple-constraint type='xs:int' predicate='http://example.com/quantity'/>
            </ps:config>
        </annotation>
    </constraint>

    <grammar xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
      <quotation>"</quotation>
      <implicit>
        <cts:and-query strength="20" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"/>
      </implicit>
      <starter strength="30" apply="grouping" delimiter=")">(</starter>
      <starter strength="40" apply="prefix" element="cts:not-query">-</starter>
      <joiner strength="10" apply="infix" element="cts:or-query" tokenize="word">OR</joiner>
      <joiner strength="20" apply="infix" element="cts:and-query" tokenize="word">AND</joiner>
      <joiner strength="30" apply="infix" element="cts:near-query" tokenize="word">NEAR</joiner>
      <joiner strength="30" apply="near2" consume="2" element="cts:near-query">NEAR/</joiner>
      <joiner strength="32" apply="boost" element="cts:boost-query" tokenize="word">BOOST</joiner>
      <joiner strength="35" apply="not-in" element="cts:not-in-query" tokenize="word">NOT_IN</joiner>
      <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint">:</joiner>
      <joiner strength="50" apply="joiner-constraint" ns="http://test/search" at="/ext/search/test-search.xqy" compare="LT" tokenize="word">LT</joiner>
      <joiner strength="50" apply="joiner-constraint" ns="http://test/search" at="/ext/search/test-search.xqy" compare="LE" tokenize="word">LE</joiner>
      <joiner strength="50" apply="joiner-constraint" ns="http://test/search" at="/ext/search/test-search.xqy" compare="GT" tokenize="word">GT</joiner>
      <joiner strength="50" apply="joiner-constraint" ns="http://test/search" at="/ext/search/test-search.xqy" compare="GE" tokenize="word">GE</joiner>
      <joiner strength="50" apply="joiner-constraint" ns="http://test/search" at="/ext/search/test-search.xqy" compare="NE" tokenize="word">NE</joiner>
    </grammar>
</options>
```

Next is the custom joiner function. It uses the custom query option configuration to decide whether to treat this as a custom constraint that can handle comparison operators. If so, it bypasses the internal MarkLogic code and returns a `custom-constraint-query` with an operator. If not, it lets MarkLogic handle it. I haven't exhaustively tested the pass-through, by the way, but it works for the simple range indexes I'm using. It's also not particularly future-proof, since it calls some undocumented MarkLogic functions directly.

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";
import module namespace searchimpl = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search-impl" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy";
import module namespace ast = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search-ast" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/ast.xqy";
import module namespace tdop     = "http://marklogic.com/parser/tdop" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/tdop.xqy";

declare namespace ps = "http://my.namespace";
declare function test:joiner-constraint(
  $ps as map:map,
  $left as element()?,
  $opts as element()?
) as element()? {
    if ($left instance of element(cts:query)) then
        (: it doesn't seem to call this function with a cts:query for a custom constraint, but the pass-through for normal range indexes does :)
        searchimpl:joiner-constraint($ps, $left)
    else 
        let $term := ast:textonly($left)
        let $symbol := searchimpl:symbol-lookup($ps)
        let $compare := ($symbol/@compare/string(), "EQ")[1]
        let $constraint := $opts/search:constraint[@name=$term]
        let $is-custom := $constraint//search:custom and $constraint//ps:config[@compareSupported=fn:true()]

        return
        if ($is-custom) then 
            let $_ := tdop:advance($ps)
            let $right := tdop:expression($ps, $symbol/@strength - 1)
            let $value := ast:textonly($right)

            return
            <search:custom-constraint-query>
                <search:constraint-name>{$term}</search:constraint-name>
                <search:text>{$value}</search:text>
                <search:range-operator>{$compare}</search:range-operator>
            </search:custom-constraint-query>
        else
            ast:joiner-constraint($ps, $left)
};
```

In the parse method I switched to the structured query parameters because this will be called via REST and it wasn't obvious how to get all of the pieces with the string query parameters. The `custom-constraint-query` created by the joiner function is passed in as the `$query-elem` parameter.

```
declare function test:parse(
  $query-elem as element(),
  $options as element(search:options)
) as schema-element(cts:query) {
...
};
```